# ArangoDB - How can I return only the _id from AQL TRAVERSAL?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to return only the `_id` from edges and vertices from the `p.path` below.

```
LET from = (
    FOR u IN products
        FILTER u.name == 'pagfr21'
        RETURN u._id
)
FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(products, productsrelated, from[0], 'outbound',
        {minDepth: 0, maxDepth: 3, paths: true})
    RETURN p.path
```

Comment: Did the reply suit your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it closed?

Comment: As of Version 2.8 (we're just starting the beta) the [new traversal feature will become available](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Aql/GraphTraversals.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `p.path` you could collect the ids of the `vertices` and `edges` subattributes and return them in two separate arrays, e.g.

```
LET from = (FOR u IN products FILTER u.name == 'foo' RETURN u._id) 

FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(products, productsrelated, from[0], 'outbound', {
  minDepth: 0, 
  maxDepth: 3, 
  paths: true 
}) 

RETURN { 
  vertices: p.path.vertices[*]._id, 
  edges: p.path.edges[*]._id 
}
```

It will return a structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "vertices": [
      "products/..."
    ],
    "edges": []
  },
  {
    "vertices": [
      "products/...",
      "products/..."
    ],
    "edges": [
      "productsrelated/..."
    ]
  },
  ...
  {
    "vertices": [
      "products/...",
      "products/...",
      "products/..."
    ],
    "edges": [
      "productsrelated/...",
      "productsrelated/..."
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Has this worked? If yes, would you mind accepting the answer in order to help potential others with the same problem?